# RXJS - Angular : Two Observable<booleans> should return Observable<boolean>

Tags: angular, rxjs, combinelatest

I want to evaluate two `observable<boolean>` and I would like to save the flow in another `observable<boolean>`.

I tried `combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$);` but it generates an `observable<[boolean, boolean]>`.

Is there a better function than `combineLatest` to evaluate both observables and returns another `observable<boolean>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use `forkJoin` here and you'll need to map these two observables into one value using `map` operator.

```js
forkJoin([observable1, observable2]).pipe(
    map(([bool1, bool2]) => {
        return bool1 & bool2;
    })
);
```

Comment: Fork join is a very specific operator. `merge`, `zip` and `combineLatest` should also be considered.

Comment: @kvetis they certainly should be. Thanks for highlighting that

Answer (score 5):

If you want to merge the result in a single stream, use `merge() from 'rxjs'`.
If you want to perform logical operation on both:

Combine latest accepted a project function as last parameter, for example
`combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$, ([first, second]) => first || second) ;`

It has been deprecated. So you need to use `map`.

```
combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$,).pipe(
    map([first, second]) => first || second)
);
```

Comment: the resultSelector is deprecated and I am gettingan advice that I should use the `pipe`operator

Comment: I did not know about deprecation. Answer is updated.